# How to delete/detect any emoji as a whole from a string in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to simulate a keyboard backspace delete event from a string in Flutter (or Dart). Something like:

```dart
String str = "hello你们‍‍"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hello你们"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hello你们"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hello你们"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hello你"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hello"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hello"
myBackspace(str) // will return "hell"
```

Comment: Could you reformulate the question please?

Comment: @Jalil what can I do to reformat the question? I am OK to reformat it, but not sure what you want me to do?

Comment: @sgon00 You question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Like explicitly ask a question

Comment: @Jalil, I have edited my question. You can have a look now. I will try to improve it again after this reply. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: What are you trying to do? in general? Just to see if there is another approach to the problem

Comment: @Jalil I just added a "PS" section in my question description. You can have a look. Basically, I want to remove all invalid chars from a string. (1) a flutter bug causes the emojis can not be deleted properly by backspace and left question mark at the end of each emoji. (2) I also need to implement a button to delete user inputs (char by char) which contain emojis too.

Comment: @HugoPassos thanks a lot for telling me this. I modified the question and the title. You can have a look now. Cheers.

Comment: If you are starting with a valid string, the problem is that you end up with a high surrogate without a low surrogate immediately following. These are [well-defined UTF-16 code unit ranges](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2). @HugoPassos explains the terminology. (I don't know Dart but I assume you could code a check.)

Comment: @TomBlodget thank you very much for the link. I am glad to hear that well-defined ranges do exist. I will try to add it to my code. And will paste the result here.

Comment: @TomBlodget thank you very much for the link. Based on the range, I have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135774/348719). It finally works. 

Comment: @TomBlodget hi, I just found a problem of my code. I can't distinguish `` and ``. So it will remove all connected emojis at once. Since `` will break to two emojis, do you have any ideas how to check if `` is one emoji instead of two? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

### Update

Dart team released a [helper package](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) that helps achieving this. `String.characters.skipLast(1)` should be able to do what you expect.

### Old answer

First, let's get to some definitions. According to [this](https://engineering.linecorp.com/en/blog/the-7-ways-of-counting-characters/) page:

1. Bytes: 8-bit. The number of bytes that a Unicode string will take up in memory or storage depends on the encoding.
2. Code Units: The smallest bit combination that can be used to express a single unit in text encoding. For example 1 code unit in UTF-8 would be 1 byte, 2 bytes in UTF-16, 4 bytes in UTF-32.
3. Code Points [or rune]: Unicode character. A single integer value (from U+0000-U+10FFFF) on a Unicode space.
4. Grapheme clusters: A single character perceived by the user. 1 grapheme cluster consists of several code points.

When you remove the last char using `substring`, you're actually removing the last code unit. If you run `print(newStr.codeUnits)` and `print(str.codeUnits)`, you'll see that the rune `128512` is equivalent to the joint of the code units `55357` and `56832`, so `55357` is actually valid, but doesn't represent anything without the "help" of another code unit.

In fact, you don't want to use `substring()` when there's non-ASCII chars in your String (like emojis or arabic letters). It'll never work. What you have to do is remove the last grapheme cluster. Something as simple as that:

```
str.graphemeClusters.removeLast()
```

However, Dart doesn't support this yet. There are several issues around this point. Some of those:
https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/34
https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/49

This lack of support seams to result in some other of issues, like the one you mentioned and this one:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31818

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. The problem is I need to implement this feature now. How can I workaround this issue? I have a string which is a mixed of english chars, asian chars, grapheme clusters etc... I need to implement a backspace action. It should delete one by one correctly. For example, `hello你` should become ``hello你` at the first backspace action and then `hello` at the second time and `hell` at the third time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot. At least not in a simple way. I have an idea to work around that, but it'll be a package and I'll take up to 1 week to create that. You would have to wait a bit.

Comment: OK, cool. I can wait. currently, I disable people to input any characters which have string length bigger than 2. and then use something like `String.fromCharCodes(sRunes, 0, sRunes.length-1)` as a workaround.

Comment: sgon00 来自中国吗？外国人可能不明白中英文一起再加上emoji是多么的痛苦！

Comment: @KennethLi 是，我现在就在中国。Yeah, I am from China. ^_^

Comment: Hi, I checked the rainbow issue (31818) you filed. I don't have that problem here. Do you mean the emoji ``? I am using the flutter master v1.5.9-pre.205.

Comment: Hi, Just FYI. I have solved the problem, and posted as an answer. It should be able to handle all kinda of emojis. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135774/348719

Comment: @sgon00 Seems like the `TextField` issue you mentioned just got fixed: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23496

Comment: @HugoPassos thanks for the info. I haven't completed flutter upgrade so I can't test it yet. The download speed is too slow and I don't want to use cn mirror, so I have to suffer the slowness.

Answer (score 7):

```
String formatText(String str) {

final RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])');

if(str.contains(regExp)){
  str = str.replaceAll(regExp,'');
}

return str; }
```

Ex: Go to https://dartpad.dev/ to test:

String str = "ThaiKV受け行くけどよね" => ThaiKV受け行くけどよね

Answer (score 3):

**This answer still has problem**

Since dart does not provide the data type 'Grapheme Cluster', I try to use method channel to do this using kotlin:

Step 1: Create a new 'Flutter Plugin' project, name the project 'gmc01', 2 files will be created automatically, namely 'gmc01.dart' and 'main.dart'.

Step 2: replace the codes in gmc01.dart with the following:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Gmc01 {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('gmc01');

  static Future<String> removeLastGMC(String strOriginal) async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('removeLastGMC', strOriginal);
    return version;
  }
}
```

Step 3: Replace the codes in main.dart with the following:

```
import 'package:gmc01/gmc01.dart';

void main() async {
  String strTemp = '12345678我们5你‍‍';
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
  strTemp = await Gmc01.removeLastGMC(strTemp);
  print(strTemp);
}
```

Step 4: Inside android/build.gradle, change the minSdkVersion from 16 to 24.

Step 5: Inside example/android/app/build.gradle, change the minSdkVersion from 16 to 24.

Step 6: Click File->Open, select gmc01->android, then click 'OK', the kotlin part of the plugin will be opened (In another Window).

Step 7: Replace the codes in Gmc01Plugin.kt with the following: (Replace the first line with your own package name)

```
package com.example.gmc01   // replace the left with your own package name

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar
import android.icu.text.BreakIterator



class Gmc01Plugin: MethodCallHandler {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
      val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), gmc01)
      channel.setMethodCallHandler(Gmc01Plugin())
    }
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    var strArg: String
    strArg = call.arguments.toString()
    var boundary = BreakIterator.getWordInstance()
    boundary.setText(strArg);
    when (call.method) {
      removeLastGMC -> {
        result.success(removeLastGMC(boundary, strArg))
      }
      else -> {
        result.notImplemented()
      }
    }
  }

  fun removeLastGMC(boundary: BreakIterator, source: String):String {
    val end = boundary.last()
    val start = boundary.previous()
    return source.substring(0, start)
  }
}
```

Step 8: Go back to the window of the plugin, and click 'Run'.

Here are the output in the console:

```
I/flutter (22855): 12345678我们5你
I/flutter (22855): 12345678我们5你
I/flutter (22855): 12345678我们5
I/flutter (22855): 12345678我们5
I/flutter (22855): 12345678我们
I/flutter (22855): 12345678
I/flutter (22855):
```

As you can see, the 'Family Emoji', 'Face Emoji' and 'Country Flag' emoji are removed correctly, but the Chinese 2 chars '我们' and the digits '12345678' are removed by using a single removeLastGMC, so still need to figure out how to distinguish Chinese Double Bytes characters / English Chars / Emojis.

BTW, I don't know how to do the Swift part, can someone help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. But it won't work when the emoji needs two char codes to represent (string length > 2). For example, ``. For emoji with string length 2, I am using `String.fromCharCodes(sRunes, 0, sRunes.length-1)`, which has similar idea as yours. I am checking Tom's comment which tells me the correct char code range.

Comment: Hi, FYI. I have solved the problem which should be able to handle any kind of emojis. Please check my own answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135774/348719

Answer (score 2):

if someone need simple solution to remove emojies from string try this.

```
String str = "hello你们‍‍"İ 
    final RegExp REGEX_EMOJI = RegExp(r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])');
    if(str.contains(REGEX_EMOJI)){
       str = str.replaceAll(REGEX_EMOJI,'');
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit unclear to what you want to check. I suggest you remove the `-1` from the substring because it will break the emoji's code snip

```
 void main() { 
   var str = "abc";
   var newStr = str.substring(0, str.length); // i removed it here
   print(newStr);
   print(newStr.runes);
   print(str.runes);
 }
```

This will give the output of

```
abc
(97, 98, 99, 128512)
(97, 98, 99, 128512)
```

Tested in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Comment: I thought my question was clear. what should i change to make my question clear? I want to find the invalid code range. I add -1 in purpose. I want to detect if a string contains an invalid char or not. In other words, 55357 is a invalid char code. and I want to know what all other invalid char codes are. Thanks.

Comment: It does not make sense to use substring to check if the string contains an invalid char. What about this string then `var str = "abc xx";` it will give the following output 
`abc x
(97, 98, 99, 128512, 32, 120)
(97, 98, 99, 128512, 32, 120, 120)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I just modified the question. You can get a better understanding what I want to achieve now. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I do understand what sgon00 wants to do: (1) for example, for any app that has a 'Text Input' widget, go inside this widget, input any emoji, and click the backspace in your virtual keyboard, you will be able to see only 'HALF OF THE EMOJI IS REMOVED' (Try yourself first!).  So his 1st question is, how to remove the whole emoji by clicking the backspace.

Comment: Question 2,  If (1) cannot be done, can we check whether a string contains HALF EMOJI  so that we can remove this half emoji programatically?

Comment: @KennethLi you are absolutely right. I will update my question with your words. :) Thanks.

Comment: If we can solve his problem (1), then just forget about (2), i.e. forget about the str.length - 1, this 'MINUS ONE', is in order to create a 'HALF EMOJI' programatically.

Answer (score 1):

## The code is not working

The code is not working properly. I just put here for reference.

### Trial 1

- Problem: can not handle  and `‍‍` properly.

```dart
String myBackspace(String str) {
  Runes strRunes = str.runes;
  str = String.fromCharCodes(strRunes, 0, strRunes.length - 1);
  print(str);
  return str;
}
```

### Trial 2

- Problem: can not handle connected emoji sequence  and `‍‍` properly.

Based on the [link](https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2)

```dart
String myBackspace(String str) {
  int i = 0;
  while (str.length > 0) {
    i++;
    int removedCharCode = str.codeUnitAt(str.length - 1);
    if (isWellFormattedUTF16(removedCharCode)) break;
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
  }
  if (i == 1) str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
  print(str);
  return str;
}

bool isWellFormattedUTF16(int charCode) {
  int surrogateLeadingStart = 0xD800;
  int surrogateLeadingEnd = 0xDBFF;
  int surrogateTrailingStart = 0xDC00;
  int surrogateTrailingEnd = 0xDFFF;
  if (!(charCode >= surrogateLeadingStart && charCode <= surrogateLeadingEnd) && 
      !(charCode >= surrogateTrailingStart && charCode <=  surrogateTrailingEnd)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: same as mine, yours doesn't work with complex emojis such as 'families emojis', e.g. this one '‍‍'.  This emoji, displayed as 'One Single Emoji with 3 peoples', when using your codes, the 3 peoples will be removed one by one.

Comment: there are some other 'single emoji' that can takes up to 8 'chars', i.e. str.length = 8

Comment: That's right. Unfortunately, the only way of doing it right is removing the grapheme cluster, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @KennethLi My code even has one more problem, will remove sequence emojis such as `` at once. I am trying to figure out how to workaround them. If this can't be done within 30 minutes, I will have to sleep first and check tomorrow. :)

Comment: I agree with Hugo Passos

Answer (score 1):

```
With RegExp and replaceAll:

 final regex = RegExp(
 "(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000- 
 \udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])");

 final textReplace = String.replaceAll(regex, '');
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a method like this one

```
bool isValid(String prevString, String newString){
  if (prevString == newString)
    return true;

  else return false; 
}
```

then in your keyboard you validate with an onChange property

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text) {
    isValid(varYouHad ,text); //validate
  },
);
```

Comment: Sorry about my English (not my native language). I think you may still misunderstand my question. The above code is just checking if two strings are the same or not. I don't know how that helps about my question. I added the [bug link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23496) in the question. I need to detect if the text is valid or not and if not, remove the unexpected char. Please let me know if my description is still not clear. I will try more words to explain.

Comment: No but its fine, because if the charcode changes the string changes too and gives you false. I tested it.

Comment: But my question is not to test if the string changes or not. My question is trying to remove the unexpected char programmatically when it exists. I will update my question description again.

Comment: I thought you wanted that because you wrote ```I am wondering if there is a invalid char code range exists, so that I can write a function to check if the character is invalid or not, for example, isValid(55357) will return false.``` hahaha no worries

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help. My main focus is `isValid(55357)` should return false. So that I know 55357 is invalid and should be removed programmatically. I have updated the question again. Hopefully, this time, it makes more sense.